# Cannot find module 'conductor-client' already install module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, conductor, netflix-conductor

I am trying to use this `module`
https://www.npmjs.com/package/conductor-client?activeTab=readme

and I run the same example given in documentation getting below error

https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-grass-ixm63

```
Error: Cannot find module 'conductor-client'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/sandbox/src/index.js:2:25)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:5
```

documentation
https://github.com/devit-tel/conductor-nodejs-client#readme

Comment: Have you installed the module?

Comment: yes see my code sandbox..!!